# Index notation with vector operators

Tags: quantum-mechanics, angular-momentum, operators, vectors, commutator

I'm new to index notation.
I'm trying to show that for to vector operators $\vec{A}$ and $\vec{B}$ the following relation holds:

$\left[ \vec{L},\: \vec{A} \cdot \vec{B}\right] = 0$

As $A$ and $B$ are both vector operators I use that

$\left[ L_i,\: A_j \right] = i \epsilon_{ijk} A_k$

same for $B_j$

After some algebra I get to:

$\left[ L_i,\: A_j B_j\right] = i \left(\epsilon_{ijk} A_j B_k + \epsilon_{ijk} A_k B_j  \right)$

At this point, I say that as $j,\: k$ are dummie indexes I can rename $j \rightarrow k$ and $k \rightarrow j$ on the second term on RHS and do an odd permutation on 
the levi civita in that same term, getting:

$\left[ L_i,\: A_j B_j\right] = i \left(\epsilon_{ijk} A_j B_k - \epsilon_{ijk} A_j B_k  \right) = 0$

Is this right? if not, why not and what would be the correct way to do this?

Any answer would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Unfortunately, check-my-work type questions are off-topic here, because the answer is typically just "yes" or "no".

Comment: (By the way, the answer is yes.)

Comment: Thanks for the answers, I was asking because I read that you can't rename indexes with other indexes involved in the same expresion, as I did above, with $k$ and $j$, why is this valid in this case? this is what I read: $3.c $http://web.iitd.ac.in/~pmvs/courses/mcl702/notation.pdf

Comment: You can't in general arbitrarily rename the indices, but the levi civita transforms in a particular way when indices are swapped in that way, so it's fine as long as you account for that.

Comment: @xish This has nothing to do with the Levi-Civita tensor. To OP: within the Einstein summation convention, you're not allowed to rename a dummy index to another that already exists. But you're not doing this. You're *interchanging* the names of two dummy indices. If it makes it more transparent, you can first rename $j$ to $m$, then $k$ to $j$, then $m$ to $k$. In each of these three steps, no dummy index appears more than twice in the expression, as is necessary, and the net result is $j \leftrightarrow k$.

Comment: @gj255 thanks so much for that clarification! it really solved my doubt